# Angular 5: AOT with a JIT module

Tags: angular, webpack

Is it possible to have an AOT-compiled application reference a JIT-compiled module?  Even if the JIT module is a separate library (referenced via the package.json)?

I need the ability to JIT compile an NgModule/Component with a dynamic template, but this isn't currently possible with AOT compilation.  So I'm left with either making the JIT component an entirely different application (undesirable), or being able to reference a separately compiled/packaged JIT module.

Edit:  perhaps using multiple entry points in Webpack for the app -- one for the main app and one for the JIT module?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by adding the component that does the dynamic compilation as an entryComponent in the module and by setting skipCodeGeneration=true in Webpack.

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample of your solution ?